# .gitginore for ignoring a submodule doesn't work as intended

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a folder called `app` in my original repository and inside it a `.gitignore` which simply ignores everything inside the folder (except itself). I would like to add a submodule inside `app` folder and I would like this submodule to be visually ignored by the original repository where I can't see the submodule directory (in GitHub where the original repo was published) but can update it and get updates when there are (since the folder will be locally there but won't be seen by the original repo).

However, whenever I try to add the submodule using `git add submodule` command, I get new changes in my original repo that I just added something. I don't want this.

Any idea to prevent this?

Comment: I am not that much knowledgeable about submodules _but_ if you want to add it inside the project _and_ not have it as a submodule of the project, would it be ok just _cloning_ what you want as the submodule into a directory of the main project? Then you should be able to ignore it from the parent project.

Comment: @eftshift0 Yes, but here's the catch: I still want to be able to update it and get updates. I merely don't want it to appear in the original repo.

Comment: you go into the ... let's call it _subproject_ and run `git pull` and such? Not enough?

Comment: Well, that it?.. Then I am kind of confused about the purpose of submodules. Sorry, I got to all this just a few hours ago.

Comment: well... what I am proposing is that you _skip_ the submodule altogether given that you do _not_ want to add it as a submodule to the project... it sounds to me like a normal standalone-project/repo inside another standalone-project/repo. And in a normal repo, well.... you pull, so.....

Comment: Well... let me write it down as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do **not** want to *link* the parent project to the submodule, then consider cloning the child project as a normal repo inside the parent project. That way, you can tell git to ignore the directory that is holding the child project and you should be fine. Being at the root of the parent project:

```
git clone url-to-child-repo child-project # use the directory of your choice, of course
```

Now that we have the project there, let's ask git to ignore it. We can either do it with .gitignore:

```
echo child-project >> .gitignore
```

Which will modify `.gitignore` and you might be tracking it or not.... or you can do it *just* for you:

```
echo child-project >> .git/info/exclude
```

And then you have the child project right there and the parent project does not *know* about it.